# MySQL view - many to one relationship in one row

Tags: mysql, view

I have a table that holds the movie information. It has ID, title and so on. I have another table called categories where I have the available categories; action, drama and so on. 
Each movie can be in many categories. So I created a view and joined these tables. Now the view displays a row for each category even if the movie is repeated.
I need to have have a single row for each movie and have categories as something like : 'Action, Drama, Comedy' (which is basically all categories from tbl_movies_categories).

How should I join tables/create view to achieve this?

Comment: Look for `group_concat()` in MySQL doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper way:
Group By a unique ID, then use group_concat() to concat the values together.

```
CREATE VIEW `vw_metadata` AS
    select 
        `vw_movies`.`id` AS `id`,
        ...
        group_concat(`vw_movies_categories`.`title_category`
            separator ',') AS `categories`,
    from
        (`vw_movies`
left join `vw_movies_categories` ON (`vw_movies_categories`.`movie_id` = `vw_movies`.`id`))
    group by `vw_movies`.`id`
```